# Sample Keyboard Driver Prevents Sign In

Tags: keyboard, driver, windows-11, system32

I'm looking into writing my own Windows keyboard layout driver since other options don't suffice and it is just some hobby project.

Now I installed [WDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) and tried the [Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples). To do so, I tried to just build the solution as release in Visual Studio. No errors or warnings.

My first attempt was to install the French keyboard layout. For this I deleted KBDFR.DLL and put the new one from my build in there (in sys32). When restarting the PC I was no longer able so sign in. I could enter my password, was able to verify it was right, and then when I hit enter or press the arrow, it flashes the screen and brings me back to the lock screen, prompting to sign in.

After restoring the system, all is fine, however, I'm clueless what I'm doing wrong. I tried to do this in the Windows Sandbox as well, and then it somehow managed to crash my actual PC upon restarting the Sandbox. Yes, sandbox crashed my PC...

I did not modify the sample files in any way, nor did I make any changes other than that DLL. Does anyone have any ideas?